# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.mod' could not be loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I try to start the bot, but I get the error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.mod' could not be loaded.

folder tree

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I34Gs.png

bot.py

```
for filename in os.listdir('./lib/cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

launcher.py

```
from lib.bot import bot


client.run('TOKEN')
```

Error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pasha\Desktop\Loli police BOT\launcher.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib.bot import bot
  File "C:\Users\pasha\Desktop\Loli police BOT\lib\bot\bot.py", line 22, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\pasha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 676, in load_extension
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.mod' could not be loaded.
```

I'm still a newbie, so I'm sorry

Comment: Have you also `setup`/added your `cog`?

Comment: Yes, I did setup in my cogs

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AGngbqU

Comment: Is there a reason to create a dir called `bot` with just one file inside of it (with the same name)? What's the purpose of that? If you move the `bot.py` file outside of the `bot` directory everything should work as expected

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the `cogs` folder under the `lib` folder. So can you try this?

```
for filename in os.listdir('./lib/cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'lib.cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```